# c++ typedef with parameters and fastcall

Tags: c++, dword

so I am looking through some source code and this one thing has stumped me. I'm kind of new to c++, so I'm having a hard time understanding what this is for. I don't really know what the following typedef is for, and how it is being used in the code below it.

```
typedef void (__fastcall *TSecType_long___SetData_t)(DWORD dwAddress, DWORD dwEDX, DWORD dwValue);
```

These are some values used for the method that uses this typedef.

```
const TSecType_long___SetData_t TSecType_long___SetData = reinterpret_cast<TSecType_long___SetData_t>(0x00518430); // 56 8B ? 8B ? ? ? ? ? 41 [3rd Result]

const DWORD *const pdwUserLocal = reinterpret_cast<const DWORD *const>(0x016A1234); // 8B ? ? ? ? ? 85 C9 74 ? 83 B8 ? ? ? ? 00 74 ? 8B ? ? ? ? ? 85 C0 7E ? 8B
const DWORD dwTeleportToggleOffset = 0x00008A94; // 8D ? ? ? ? ? 8B ? 8B ? E8 ? ? ? ? 85 ? 0F 85 ? ? ? ? 39 ? ? ? ? ?
const DWORD dwTeleportYOffset = 0x00008AAC; // 8D ? ? ? ? ? ? 8B ? E8 ? ? ? ? 6A ? 8B ? E8 ? ? ? ? 6A 00 68 ? ? ? ?
const DWORD dwTeleportXOffset = dwTeleportYOffset + 0x0C;
```

And for the method itself:

```
bool Teleport(_In_ int nX, _In_ int nY)
{
__try
{
    {

        DWORD dwUserLocal = *pdwUserLocal;
        TSecType_long___SetData(dwUserLocal + dwTeleportToggleOffset, NULL, 0);
        TSecType_long___SetData(dwUserLocal + dwTeleportXOffset, NULL, nX);
        TSecType_long___SetData(dwUserLocal + dwTeleportYOffset, NULL, nY);
        TSecType_long___SetData(dwUserLocal + dwTeleportToggleOffset, NULL, 1);
    }
}
__except (EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)
{
    return false;
}
return true;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: What kind of code is that? Did this come out of some c++ de-compiler perhaps? (didn't know there are any, but I cannot imagine human writing code like this). If it is, then it's not doing very good job.

Comment: @j_kubik, It's a hack for a game (or at least looks like one). Not quite sure what purpose all the long types/names that use reserved identifiers are for, though.

Comment: My question was rather: where did you get this code from? PS And as chris wrote:what iexactly is your question? You cannot expect anyone just to tell you what a piece of code out of context is doing.

Comment: my question, how exactly is the *TSecType_long___SetData_t typedef being used in the teleport method? I also didn't understand the decleration since it had parameters and used __fastcall.

Comment: @user1583852, `__fastcall` is a calling convention. The whole thing is a function pointer.

Comment: ok that was actually all i needed haha. for some reason i wasnt seeing that it was a function pointer (too long away from c), thank you chris :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working under the assumption that you know what a `typedef` is (it's taking a datatype and giving it another name), all that this is - is a function typedef. In other words, `TSecType_long___SetData_t` is a function that takes 3 `DWORD` arguments and returns a `void`.

In your case, someone has a-priori knowledge that the address 0x00518430 contains a function that can be called given the `TSecType_long___SetData_t` API. In order to make that address callable, the address is reinterpreted as the function datatype and assigned to the variable `TSecType_long___SetData`.

Answer (score 0):

Just like @chris said `TSecType_long___SetData_t` is just a declaration of a pointer to function, thus having parameters. And the following line:

```
const TSecType_long___SetData_t TSecType_long___SetData = einterpret_cast<TSecType_long___SetData_t>(0x00518430);
```

defines a variable of that type and assigns it a value, which in this case seems to be a hardcoded memory location (which I don't know where that comes from). All other occurrences are just simple function calls.
A little googling on function pointers should give you whatever you need to know about them.